# Convert PNG to Multi-page PDF

Tags: mac, unix, pdf, imagemagick, png

I've seen a lot of posts about how to convert a multi-page PDF to PNG but I'm wondering how I can go in the opposite direction if I have the size of each page I want made.

Answer (score 1):

Print the PNG files to PDF. By default, the PDF pages will all be the same size but you can crop them down once it is created.

Comment: I think he may be looking for a series of commands.

Comment: @ShaneDiDona Ideally yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ShaneDiDona: why a 'series of commands' if a simple one is all you need?   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have PNG files `page1.png`, `page2.png`,... `page9.png` and you want to create a 9-page PDF from these input PNGs.

The following simple ImageMagick command does create this PDF:

```
 convert page*.png 9page.pdf
```

If you want to re-sort the pages, just list all the PNGs in the order you want:

```
convert     \
  page8.png \
  page7.png \
  page6.png \
  page9.png \
  page1.png \
  page2.png \
  page3.png \
  page4.png \
  page5.png \
  9page.pdf
```

Comment: Strange doing that, I get the number of pages, but only the first pages shows anything ;( ➜  2018-11-29 convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-14 Q16 x86_64 2018-10-25 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma png tiff webp xml zlib